# Compare time offset of all domain-controllers in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, time, domaincontroller

I would like to compare all domain-controllers' time difference via PowerShell.

I found something like this:

```
$output1 = & w32tm /monitor /domain:mydomain.local /threads:5
    $stdOutStart = 8
    $output = $output1[$stdOutStart..$output1.Length]
```

I want to extract the data of `$output` and compare only the `ntp` offset time, and if it is more than one second it should send a mail alert.

the `$output` is not an object, its just text, how can I extract the needed fields?

```
$output looks like
server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]:
    ICMP: 1ms delay
    **NTP: +0.0017247s offset** from server1.mydomain.local
        RefID: server1.mydomain.local [192.168.22.122.]
        Stratum: 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't mean to keep this going but a few point's that I can't make in a comment.

w32tm.exe can indeed return a negative number for example -1.001755 .  That's not accommodated in the latest answer.  Also, I'd use `-ge` & `-le` instead of `-gt` & `-lt`, as there's an edge case of the difference being +- exactly 1 second.  I know that's probably trivial in a script like this, but it also doesn't cost anything to be thorough.

I'd establish the `$mailParams` hash before the For loop and only reset the value of body in the if block.

I'm not exactly sure why we're using the `[Double]::Parse()` method.  I work in the US where there's less need for globalization features.  However, in quick testing I don't see any difference in the outcome.  Happy to have that explained further.

The key to this was the ability to look backward through the array relative to the NTP line.  How we're matching / identifying the line and splitting thereafter is a matter of preference I suppose.  However, I did find a flaw in my approach, because "NTP: error" might get echoed in some cases.  That's simple enough to fix without the more elaborate RegEx.  I added the error lines to the sample output just to cover it in further examples.

I think you like the more RegEx intense approach and of course using it helps us learn.  As such I'm going to give both adjusted examples below below.

You should also decide if you want to receive multiple email alerts or just 1 email with all the alert data per/run.  Since we all suffer from some degree of email overload I'd imagine it's the latter, but I put a Boolean variable in there so you can decide for yourself.

I made a comment in my original answer to polish up the `$CurrentServer`.  @Theo did that with `.TrimEnd(':')`, however I think we can take that further.  At first I thought this is a port number I can do something like `-replace ":\d{1,5}:"` that's going to chop the trailing colon 1-5 digits colon.  It worked but doesn't feel right.  The possibility of NTP straying from well known port 123 is extremely remote. So, instead let's chop it using a literal match like `-replace ":123]:","]"` Note: `.Replace(":123]:", "]")` would probably work just as well.

Example Output from w32tm:

```
# Sample Output, in practice set this to the output of w32tm.exe
$W32t_Output =
@(
'server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]:'
'    ICMP: 1ms delay'
'    NTP: +0.0017247s offset from server1.mydomain.local'
'        RefID: server1.mydomain.local [192.168.22.122.]'
'        Stratum: 3'
'server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]:'
'    ICMP: 1ms delay'
'    NTP: -1.0017247s offset from server1.mydomain.local'
'        RefID: server1.mydomain.local [192.168.22.122.]'
'        Stratum: 3'
'server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]:'
'    ICMP: 1ms delay'
'    NTP: +2.0017247s offset from server1.mydomain.local'
'        RefID: server1.mydomain.local [192.168.22.122.]'
'        Stratum: 3'
'server2.mydomain.local[192.168.200.200:123]:'
'    ICMP: 0ms delay'
'    NTP: error ERROR_TIMEOUT - no response from server in 1000ms'
'DownServer.mydomain.local [error WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND]'
)
```

Example 1 using my original approach:

```
# > Set $OneAlert to true if you want 1 alert for all the interesting time variances per run.
# > Set to false if you want a single alert for each interesting variance encountered per run.
$OneAlert       = $true
$Body           = [Collections.ArrayList]@()
$AlertThreshold = 1 # Number of seconds before an alert...

$mailParams = 
@{
    To         = 'someone@yourdomain.com'
    From       = 'ntpchecker@yourdomain.com'
    SmtpServer = 'mailserver.yourdomain.com'
    Subject    = 'Alert Server Time Difference'
    Body       = ''
    Priority   = 'High'
}

For( $i = 0; $i -lt $W32t_Output.Length; ++$i )
{
    $CurrentLine = $W32t_Output[$i].Trim()

    If( $CurrentLine -match '^NTP: ' -and $CurrentLine -notmatch 'error' )
    {
        $CurrentLineFields = $CurrentLine.Split(' ')                    # Break up the NTP line, as long as the output is predictable this should work.
        [Double]$OffSet    = $CurrentLineFields[1].Replace('s','')      # The second index should be the offset, clean it up to be a number...
        $DiffServer        =  $CurrentLineFields[-1]                    # Last thing on the current line should be the server is offset from.
        $CurrentServer     = $W32t_Output[$i-2] -replace ":123]:","]"   # Look back through the output array to get the current server. 

        # Logic for echoing and/or email alerting:
        If( $OffSet -ge $AlertThreshold -or $OffSet -le -$AlertThreshold )
        {
            If($OneAlert)
            {
                [Void]$Body.Add( "Alert : $CurrentServer time offset $Offset seconds from $DiffServer !" )
            }
            Else
            {
                $mailParams['Body'] = "Alert : $CurrentServer time offset $Offset seconds from $DiffServer !"
                Send-MailMessage @mailParams
            }
        }
    }
}

# $Body will only be populated if $OneAlert is true
If( $Body )
{
    $mailParams['body'] = $Body -join "`r`n"
    Send-MailMessage @mailParams   
}
```

Example 2 further combining @Theo 's approach:

```
# > Set $OneAlert to true if you want 1 alert for all the interesting time variances per run.
# > Set to false if you want a single alert for each interesting variance encountered per run.
$OneAlert       = $false
$Body           = [Collections.ArrayList]@()
$AlertThreshold = 1 # Number of seconds before an alert...

$mailParams = 
@{
    To         = 'someone@yourdomain.com'
    From       = 'ntpchecker@yourdomain.com'
    SmtpServer = 'mailserver.yourdomain.com'
    Subject    = 'Alert Server Time Difference'
    Body       = ''
    Priority   = 'High'
}

for( $i = 0; $i -lt $output.Count; $i++ ) {
    if ($output[$i] -match 'NTP:\s+([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)s') {
        $seconds = [double]::Parse($matches[1], [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

        # Adjusted the if condition a little:
        if ( $seconds -ge $AlertThreshold -or $seconds -le -$AlertThreshold ) {
            $currentServer = $output[$i - 2] -replace ":123]:","]" # changed a little
            $refServer = ($output[$i] -split ' ')[-1]

            If($OneAlert) # prepare to send an email alert
            {
                [Void]$Body.Add( "Alert: $currentServer time offset $seconds seconds from $refServer !" )
            }
            Else
            {
                $mailParams['body'] = "Alert: $currentServer time offset $seconds seconds from $refServer !"
                Send-MailMessage @mailParams
            }
        }
    }
}

# $Body will only be populated if $OneAlert is true
If( $Body )
{
    $mailParams['body'] = $Body -join "`r`n"
    Send-MailMessage @mailParams   
}
```

Obviously this is a little blue sky, and I probably got carried away.  At any rate let me/us know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the NTP offset in `$output` into a [Double] and if that is greater than 1, send the email alert.

Something like this:

```
if ($output -match 'NTP:\s+([+-]?\d(?:\.\d+)?)s') {
    $seconds = [double]::Parse($matches[1], [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
    if ($seconds -gt 1) {
        # send an email alert
    }
}
```

Regex details:

> ```
> NTP:             Match the characters “NTP:” literally
> \s               Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>    +             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> [+-]             Match a single character present in the list below
>                  The character “+”
>                  The character “-”
>    ?             Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> (                Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
>    \d            Match a single digit 0..9
>    (?:           Match the regular expression below
>       \.         Match the character “.” literally
>       \d         Match a single digit 0..9
>          +       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    )?            Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> )               
> s                Match the character “s” literally
> ```

---

As requested in your comment, you could merge my code with [Stevens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60417454/9898643).
As you already have the lines in an array variable called `$output`, I will use that name.

Example:

> ```
> $output = @"
> server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]:
>     ICMP: 1ms delay
>     NTP: +0.0017247s offset from server1.mydomain.local
>         RefID: server1.mydomain.local [192.168.22.122.]
>         Stratum: 3
> server3.mydomain.local[192.168.22.23:123]:
>     ICMP: 1ms delay
>     NTP: +1.0017555s offset from server1.mydomain.local
>         RefID: server1.mydomain.local [192.168.22.122.]
>         Stratum: 3
> server4.mydomain.local[192.168.22.24:123]:
>     ICMP: 1ms delay
>     NTP: +21.095731s offset from server1.mydomain.local
>         RefID: server1.mydomain.local [192.168.22.122.]
>         Stratum: 3
> "@ -split '\r?\n'
> ```

The code could then be:

```
$AlertThreshold = 1 # Number of seconds before an alert...

for( $i = 0; $i -lt $output.Count; $i++ ) {
    if ($output[$i] -match 'NTP:\s+([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)s') {
        $seconds = [double]::Parse($matches[1], [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
        if ($seconds -gt $AlertThreshold) {
            # prepare to send an send an email alert
            $currentServer = $output[$i - 2].TrimEnd(":")
            $refServer = ($output[$i] -split ' ')[-1]
            $message = "Alert: $currentServer time offset $seconds seconds from $refServer !"
            Write-Host $message
            # send the message
            $mailParams = @{
                To         = 'someone@yourdomain.com'
                From       = 'ntpchecker@yourdomain.com'
                SmtpServer = 'mailserver.yourdomain.com'
                Subject    = 'Alert Server Time Difference'
                Body       = $message
                Priority   = 'High'
                # etc.
            }
            # Send-MailMessage @mailParams
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

> ```
> Alert: server3.mydomain.local[192.168.22.23:123] time offset 1.0017555 seconds from server1.mydomain.local !
> Alert: server4.mydomain.local[192.168.22.24:123] time offset 21.095731 seconds from server1.mydomain.local !
> ```

Comment: do you have an example to to it with this way?                                                              if ($output -match 'NTP:\s+([+-]?\d(?:\.\d+)?)s') {
    $seconds = [double]::Parse($matches[1], [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
    if ($seconds -gt 1) {
        # send an email alert
    }
}

Comment: @vespavbb As requested, I have 'merged' my code with Steven's. Because your example output was limited to just one server, the first answer only tackled the parsing of the NTP offset. It now also shows you how to create and send the alert by email. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply it looks like a interesting solution. Not sure how to pic the ntp number, for me it will be ok if a mismatch is on seconds, if the first Number -ne"0" NTP: -**0**.0022387s from the complete output. (in the output there will be about 5 servers..)

```
$output1 = & w32tm /monitor /domain:mydomain.local /threads:5

$stdOutStart = 8
$output = $output1[$stdOutStart..$output1.Length]
$timeInfos = @()

for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $output.Length ; $i+=4) {
        $server = $output[$i].Split(' ')[0]
        $icmp = $output[$i+1].Trim().Split(' ')[1]
        $offset = $output[$i+2].Trim().Split(' ')[1]
        $timeInfos += New-Object PsObject -Property @{
            Server = $server
            ICMP = $icmp
            Offset = $offset
        }
}

$timeInfos

if ($output -match 'NTP:\s+([+-]?\d(?:\.\d+)?)s') {
    $seconds = [double]::Parse($matches[1], [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
    if ($seconds -gt 1) {
        Write-host " send an email alert..#mail script here"
    }

    else
    {
    Write-host " everything ok"

    }
    }
```

Comment: Darn I wish I knew you were on the same path.  Take a look at my answer though.  I think the difference is I'm looking for other data relative to where I find "NTP:" .  Your code is slicing off the first 8 elements then stepping the array in 4 element chunks.  I don't think the output is reliable enough for that, for example if a server errors-out...  In my environment I have several servers that aren't online...  You can easily adjust my example to do the custom object array or build up a string body.

Answer (score 0):

@Theo RegEx skills are something I just can't -match... See what I did there.

Seriously one of these days I'll get more fluent with RegEx, for now I'm stuck doing things the hard way.  In this case I would think you want a little more information in your alert.  To me that means stepping back through the output to get the server who's offset from another server is beyond the desired threshold.  I typically use a traditional For loop, because I can change the value of the iteration variable to look back or forward through the array.

```
    $Arr =
@(
'server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]:'
'    ICMP: 1ms delay'
'    NTP: +0.0017247s offset from server1.mydomain.local'
'        RefID: server1.mydomain.local [192.168.22.122.]'
'        Stratum: 3'
'server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]:'
'    ICMP: 1ms delay'
'    NTP: +0.0017247s offset from server1.mydomain.local'
'        RefID: server1.mydomain.local [192.168.22.122.]'
'        Stratum: 3'
'server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]:'
'    ICMP: 1ms delay'
'    NTP: +0.0017247s offset from server1.mydomain.local'
'        RefID: server1.mydomain.local [192.168.22.122.]'
'        Stratum: 3'
)

$AlertThreshold = .0016 # Number of seconds before an alert...

For( $i = 0; $i -lt $Arr.Length; ++$i )
{
    $CurrentLine = $Arr[$i].Trim()
    # $CurrentLine

    If( $CurrentLine -match '^NTP: ')
    {
        # Break up the NTP line, as long as the output is predictable this should work.
        $CurrentLineFields = $CurrentLine.Split(' ')

        # The second index should be the offset, clean it up to be a number...
        [Double]$OffSet = $CurrentLineFields[1].Replace('s','')

        # Last thing on the current line should be the server is offset from.
        $DiffServer = $CurrentLineFields[-1]

        # Look back through the output array to get the current server.
        $CurrentServer = $Arr[$i-2] #May need some more work here to polish up the output.

        # Logic for echoing and/or email alerting:
        If( $OffSet -ge $AlertThreshold -or $OffSet -le -$AlertThreshold )
        {
            Write-Host "Alert : $CurrentServer time offset $Offset seconds from $DiffServer !"
            # You can send the email here of build up an email body for a single email alert that will
            # all the curious offsets...
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Alert : server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]: time offset 0.0017247 seconds from server1.mydomain.local !
Alert : server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]: time offset 0.0017247 seconds from server1.mydomain.local !
Alert : server2.mydomain.local[192.168.22.22:123]: time offset 0.0017247 seconds from server1.mydomain.local !
```

- Obviously I just repeated the data you gave.  I'm not sitting in an AD environment at the moment.  In your case you want to assign a variable to the output of w32tm.exe
- I don't know if if the offset could ever be negative so I accommodated that scenario.
- Adjust the threshold variable as needed.  I obviously changed it to test.
- Comments are for your benefit, if you remove them it much more concise.

Tell me if this is crazy.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: awesome! I´m impressed

Comment: That's great! I only say because you're a new contributor, but if you like the answer you can accept by clicking the check mark to the left. Depending on your privileges you can also upvote answers and comments if they add positively to the conversation.